# Why is Salesforce inspector faster than data loader or workbench?

Tags: data-loader, performance, workbench, bulk-delete

I have a use case where I need to delete a few million duplicates from my org. I have explored the following 3 tools to achieve this. Salesforce Inspector, Data Loader and Workbench. The performance of Salesforce inspector is exponentially faster than other two.
Assuming that all of them use the bulk APIs for mass delete why would the performance of one be so different and better than the rest two? Can someone help me understand?

Comment: You cannot assume that all tools use bulk API and parallel processing. For instance in Dataloader that's a configurable option. Are you sure they are all set up the same way? And did you do multiple runs of all 3 to ensure there were no network hiccups or other differences at the time of execution?

Comment: For my test run, i attempted to delete 200K records. It took approx 5 minutes via SF Inspector to process all 200K. However, with data loader, with parallel processing, it took close to 1 hour. Workbench was a little better between 10-15 minutes each time. However, workbench kept throwing up a CSRF token error intermittently for no obvious reasons..